# How to refresh resources without quitting sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

Using sbt 1.3.x and I've never been able to change contents of `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` and have them updated when I run `reload` from the `sbt` CLI interface. Is this possible? It's annoying to have to quit and reload sbt every time I change something in a resource file. For example, I am playing around with a logging configuration.

Comment: Aren't you using some weird sbt plugins (Play adds a lot)? Update of resources shouldn't require `reload` but `compile` like everything that is source dependency. Also by default resources are `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` - did you change that or is this a typo?

Comment: Not using any strange plugins. Ok so I can modify file contents of a file within `src/test/resources` and run tests and they should use the modified files? It seems to be working sometimes and not working other times. Maybe running `Test / compile` before running tests would help, but I assume that's done anyways. Thanks for the response.

Comment: If you changed resource files, it should copy them to compilation output. If that is not discovered I would consider it a bug and reported it.